# Positive directional derivative for linesearch

Tags: scipy

What does the smode of scipy.optimize 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch' mean?

for example in fmin_slsqp
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html

Comment: Please give a link to the documentation page.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These optimization algorithms typically work by choosing a descent direction, and then performing a line search to that direction. I think this message means that the optimizer got into a position where it did not manage to find a direction where the value of the objective function decreases (fast enough), but could also not verify that the current position is a minimum.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. Your describing a local minimum. Pretty sure SLSQP isn't going to throw error when it finds a local minimum. I *think* it's more, the gradient is non zero at x, but line search along the gradient did not yield a smaller value, therefore your gradient is erroneous.

Answer (score 22):

I still don't know what it means but how to solve it. Basically, the function that is optimized needs to return a smaller value.

```
F(x):
    ...
    return value / 10000000
```

Comment: The more general answer is that the function that is being optimized is poorly scaled. I think the ideal is that the function being optimized over should tend to give a mean somewhere in the range 1-5. For my usecase, I had to multiply by 1000.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you are dividing the function to be optimized by `n` to coax the method to work, what do you do with the values `x` in the solutions?

Comment: @Windstorm1981, if you only scale the objective, then the solution values `x` should be good as is. If, however, you also scaled the input values, then you have to reverse the scaling at the end to get out the actual solution. For these problems it is actually best if all values, both inputs and objectives, are scaled to be order 1. It takes some effort to implement this scaling and un-scaling at the end, but if the optimization problem is large, this should help convergence a lot.

Comment: @jebob Do you have a source for the optimal range 1-5 ?

Comment: @scleronomic https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/toolbox/presolver.html says "same order of magnitude". https://www.gams.com/blog/2017/08/scaling/ says a range of four orders of magnitude and around 1. I don't have a good source for <1 order of magnitude.

Comment: I searched two days how to fix this issue thanks so much !!!!

Comment: Don't you need to scale the ydata accordingly?

Answer (score 7):

To avoid changing your function you can also try experimenting with the ftol and eps parameters. Changing ftol to a higher value is equivalent to changing the function to a smaller value.

Comment: better suited as comment

Comment: True that. I made a mistake when posting and did not know how to correct it.

Answer (score 6):

One situation in which you receive this error, is when

1. `x0` is outside the valid range you defined in `bounds`.
2. and the unconstrained maximum is attained for values outside `bounds`.

I will set up a hypothetical optimization problem, run it with two different initial values and print the output of `scipy.optimize`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

H = np.array([[2., 0.],
              [0., 8.]])

c = np.array([0, -32])

x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5])    # valid initial value
x1 = np.array([-1, 1.1])     # invalid initial value

def loss(x, sign=1.):
    return sign * (0.5 * np.dot(x.T, np.dot(H, x)) + np.dot(c, x))

def jac(x, sign=1.):
    return sign * (np.dot(x.T, H) + c)

bounds = [(0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

Now that loss function, gradient, x0 and bounds are in place, we can solve the problem:

```
def solve(start):
    res = optimize.minimize(fun=loss, 
                            x0=start, 
                            jac=jac, 
                            bounds=bounds,
                            method='SLSQP')
    return res



solve(x0)   # valid initial value
# fun: -27.999999999963507
# jac: array([ 2.90878432e-14, -2.40000000e+01])
# message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
# ...
#  status: 0
# success: True
# x: array([1.45439216e-14, 1.00000000e+00])

solve(x1)      # invalid initial value:
#  fun: -29.534653465326528
#  jac: array([ -1.16831683, -23.36633663])
#  message: 'Positive directional derivative for linesearch'
#  ...
#  status: 8
#  success: False
#  x: array([-0.58415842,  1.07920792])
```

As @pv. pointed out in the accepted answer, the algorithm can't verify that this is a minimum:

> I think this message means that the optimizer got into a position where it did not manage to find a direction where the value of the objective function decreases (fast enough), but could also not verify that the current position is a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer, but you can see the source code that generates the smode here:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/slsqp/slsqp_optmz.f

Assignments of `mode = 8` (the "Positive directional derivative for linesearch" you are asking about) can be found in lines 412 and 486. If can figure out why they are assigned in the code, you've got your answer.

Comment: Here is a permanent link for the record https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/699529f913ffa71929a420451294865e94b6ba0e/scipy/optimize/slsqp/slsqp_optmz.f#L506-L523

Answer (score 0):

I had been getting the same error. As per my understanding, this essentially means that the iterative solution has arrived at a point that lies outside the search space (as per the constraints / bounds) and yet the result got stuck in the local minima - 'linesearch' here means that a step in any direction, i.e. any move from the current point results in a 'positive gradient'

A few things that you can try to overcome this:

1. (This worked for me) Ensure that your bounds and constraints are all scaled. For example, suppose you have constraints:

   > f(x)>=0 and g(x)>=0

   Then make sure that the upper bounds of both f(x) and g(x) are of similar orders of magnitude. Even though f(x)=10 and g(x)=100000 might be a correct solution, the optimization method won't likely arrive at that.
2. Play with tolerance parameters. These could vary based on the method being used for optimization. For example, 'maxcv' parameter is really helpful in identifying the extent to which each constraint is getting violated.
3. Try relaxing the constraints to understand which one is unreasonably directing the iterations outside the search space.
4. Try different optimization methods, based on the optimization problem.