# How do I set the tolerance in scipy.optimize.minimize()?

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scientific-computing

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize to solve for an efficient portfolio.

With the default settings I am frequently running into "BaseException: Positive directional derivative for linesearch" errors for when using certain inputs.  I noticed if I set the tolerance high enough, the problem becomes less but doesn't go away.  Any advice?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize


def fx(TOLERANCE):
    #TOLERANCE = 1.5

    def solve_weights(R, C, rf, b_):
        def port_mean_var(W,R,C):
            return sum(R*W), np.dot(np.dot(W, C), W)
        def fitness(W, R, C, rf):
            mean, var = port_mean_var(W, R, C)    # calculate mean/variance of the portfolio
            util = (mean - rf) / np.sqrt(var)        # utility = Sharpe ratio
            return 1/util                        # maximize the utility, minimize its inverse value
        n = len(R)
        W = np.ones([n])/n                        # start optimization with equal weights
        #b_ = [(0.,1.) for i in range(n)]    # weights for boundaries between 0%..100%. No leverage, no shorting
        c_ = ({'type':'eq', 'fun': lambda W: sum(W)-1. })    # Sum of weights must be 100%
        optimized = scipy.optimize.minimize(fitness, W, (R, C, rf), 
                                            method='SLSQP', constraints=c_, 
                                            bounds=b_, tol=TOLERANCE)    
        if not optimized.success: 
            raise BaseException(optimized.message)
        return optimized.x

    def mean_var_opt2(ret_df, upper_bounds=None):
        R = (ret_df.mean(0)*252).values
        C = (ret_df.cov()*252).values
        rf = 0.0
        if upper_bounds == None:
            upper_bounds = pd.Series(1.0,index=ret_df.columns)
        b_ = [(0.0,float(num)) for num in upper_bounds]
        wgts = solve_weights(R, C, rf, b_)
        return pd.Series(wgts, index=ret_df.columns)


    np.random.seed(45)
    rets = []
    for i in range(10000):
        rets.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4)/100.0))

    try:
        for i in range(10000):
            mean_var_opt2(rets[i])
    except BaseException as e:
        print e
    finally: print "Tolerance: %s, iter: %s" % (TOLERANCE,i)

for k in [0.001, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 5.0, 50.0, 500.0]:
    fx(k)


Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 0.001, iter: 0
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 0.01, iter: 30
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 0.025, iter: 77
Inequality constraints incompatible
Tolerance: 0.05, iter: 212
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 0.1, iter: 444
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 0.5, iter: 444
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 1.0, iter: 1026
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 5.0, iter: 1026
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 50.0, iter: 1026
Positive directional derivative for linesearch
Tolerance: 500.0, iter: 1026
```

Comment: The question title is misleading -- your example demonstrates that you already know how to set the tolerance. But that's not really what you're asking about anyway

Answer (score 2):

I am providing an answer at this late date because it seems that the source code for this example is still up on the web, [here](https://github.com/omartinsky/QuantAndFinancial/blob/master/black_litterman/black_litterman.ipynb).

In order to maximize the Sharpe ratio as in the function `fitness()` it is not necessary to minimize the reciprocal of it; you can simply minimize the negative of it.

Thus if I replace `return 1/util` with `return -util` in that function and run the questioner's code--- I did that--- I find that there are no errors for any of the 10,000 iterations for any `TOLERANCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Tuning the tolerance until it doesn't crash is a very weak solution, a small change on your data or function, and you are bound to crash. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155721/positive-directional-derivative-for-linesearch) what does your error message mean.

My guess is that the constrains are not playing nicely. Solvers work best on smooth functions, and your constrains can make the problem quite difficult. I can think of two ways to solve this:

- Include the constrain in your problem definition: the algorithm tries to fit the first N-1 values for `W`, and you compute the last one from them. With this approach you may find yourself getting in negative weights.
- Add the constrain in the objective function. Removing the constrain, take the weights, normalise them so they add up to 1, and add to the return value `(W.sum() - 1)**2`. This behaviour is parabolic in `W`, that is what solvers work best in. In the final result, the weights may not exactly add up to 1, but as you are internally using them normalised, it should not be a problem.

An alternative approach is to reduce the number of free parameters. If `W[17]` has a similar meaning to `W[18]`, one may naturally expect their values to be similar. You can then compute them using a smooth function, for example, a parabola, or a few terms in a sin/cosine series. This allows you to introduce locality information and reduce the number of dimensions of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`SLSQP` requires the cost function to be twice derivable, and it may fail hard if that condition is not met. No amount of tolerance increase will help you unless it's so large that you'll always get the initial solution.

You may want to try `COBYLA` instead -- note, however, that this would require you to transform your bounds into constraints, as`COBYLA` does not accept a separate bounds argument.