# Setting Scipy inequality constraints for Minimisation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook

I have recently run into this problem.

I am given a task to solve this optimisation problem.

[image]

Here is how I setup my code.

```
# import libraries
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

# Declare objective function
def objective_fun(x):
    return 49500*x[0] + 50000*x[1] + 61000*x[2] + 63500*x[3] + 66500*x[4] + 71000*x[5] + 72500*x[6] + 80000*x[7]

# Declare equality constraint 1
def constraint1(x):
    sum_con1 = 1225
    for i in range(7):
         sum_con1 = sum_con1 - x[i]

    return sum_con1

# Declare inequality constraint 2
def constraint2(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] + x[3] + x[5] - 612.5

# Declare inequality constraint 3
def constraint3(x):
    
    return 650 - x[0] + x[2] + x[6] + x[7]

# Declare inequality constraint 4
def constraint4(x):
    
    return 720 - x[1] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5]

# Declare inequality constraint 5
def constraint5(x):
    
    return 0.15*x[0] + 0.16*x[1] + 0.18*x[2] + 0.2*x[3] + 0.21*x[4] + 0.22*x[5] + 0.23*x[6] + 0.25*x[7] - 232.75

# Set scipy constraints
con1 = {"type": "eq", "fun" : constraint1}
con2 = {"type": "ineq", "fun" : constraint2}
con3 = {"type": "ineq", "fun" : constraint3}
con4 = {"type": "ineq", "fun" : constraint4}
con5 = {"type": "ineq", "fun" : constraint5}
cons = [con1, con2, con3, con4, con5]

# Set boundaries
b_0 = (0.0, 300.0)
b_1 = (0.0, 600.0)
b_2 = (0.0, 510.0)
b_3 = (0.0, 655.0)
b_4 = (0.0, 575.0)
b_5 = (0.0, 680.0)
b_6 = (0.0, 450.0)
b_7 = (0.0, 490.0)
bnds = (b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5, b_6, b_7)

# Set initial guess
i_0 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

# Optimise minimise the function using scipy minimise
sol = minimize(objective_fun, i_0, method='SLSQP', bounds = bnds, constraints = cons)

# visualising the solution
print(sol)
```

When I run the code, the success is False and the x values don't seem to be optimised.

I am wondering if my setup is incorrect or are there something I have missed when attempting this task.

Comment: Your implementation is correct, but the problem is badly scaled. Try for example to multiply the `objective_fun(x)` by  `1/1000` . See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155721/positive-directional-derivative-for-linesearch) question. One comment mentions that the optimal range for the objective is between 1 and 5...

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of investigations, I have found a problem with my code.

The return statements on the inequality constraints need a bracket on the LHS bits.

For example,

```
def constraint2(x):
    return (x[0] + x[1] + x[3] + x[5]) - 612.5

# Declare inequality constraint 3
def constraint3(x):
    
    return 650 - (x[0] + x[2] + x[6] + x[7])

# Declare inequality constraint 4
def constraint4(x):
    
    return 720 - (x[1] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5])

# Declare inequality constraint 5
def constraint5(x):
    
    return (0.15*x[0] + 0.16*x[1] + 0.18*x[2] + 0.2*x[3] + 0.21*x[4] + 0.22*x[5] + 0.23*x[6] + 0.25*x[7]) - 232.75
```

Without the brackets, the result of the minimisation is

x = [0.0, 600.0, 0.0, 111.0, 184.0,0.0, 330.0, 0.0]

With the brackets,

x = [55.0, 600.0, 0.0, 20.0, 100.0, 0.0, 450.0, 0.0]

I know that with the brackets result is correct since I have done the calculation using Excel beforehand.

A lot of tutorials online do not mention the requirement of brackets on the inequality constraints.

Comment: I did try rescaling as you have mentioned. I have multiplied my objecitve_fun() by 1/1000 and 1/100 but those do not give me a correct result. I have checked my work again and found out that the only constraint that needs brackets is constraint 4. I am not too sure why it behaves this way.

Comment: Ah now I see. I did not read careful enough. Of course `a-b+c` is different from `a-(b+c) = a-b-c` So those brackets are not just for show but serve a mathematical purpose. You have to model your constraints correctly. So constraint 3 and 4 need the brackets. If the result is the same when you remove the brackets for constraint 3 it means that this constraint is not active.

Comment: I realised that as well. I initially took the minus sign as inequality signs at first. The tutorials in which I have learnt are not really mentioning the use of brackets that's why I am not quite sure at first and post the question.